# shutdown asks for password even after adding to sudoers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, sudoers

I'm trying to reboot my Linux machine running in VM and I'm calling the following in a bash script:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -r 5
```

I have the following added to my sudoers:

```
%myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /etc/init.d
```

Yet upon running my script, It still prompts for a password

```
[sudo] password for myuser:
```

What else should I be doing?

Comment: `%myuser` refers to the __group__ `myuser`. Is that intended? If you want to specify the __user__, remove that `%`

Comment: No i guess not, I have just tried with %group and with just "user ALL=(ALL)..." , yet still asks password

Comment: Also keep in mind the order of the statements. What happens when you move that line to the bottom or to the top of that file? (At least to the top of the rulesets)

Comment: Moved it to the top and same thing unfortunately. It was to the bottom earliar.

Comment: Then `(ALL)` interferes here. Try `myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /etc/init.d`, my last guess

Comment: Still prompting, however, I think the reboot command might be a better fit here, and that is currently not asking for password, even though it is in sudoers the same way. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add `*` after `/sbin/shutdown*` so that it will also allow passing args to the command - that's why reboot works if you pass no args.

Comment: @user3128077, have you ever considered "accepting" any answer given to you by clicking on the checkmark?